# Como remover item de lista dentro de loop?

Tags: python

Estou tentando deletar um item dentro de um loop.
Já fiquei sabendo que não é possível.
Estou vendo como implementar uma lista compreensiva.

Mas não entendi ainda como ela funciona. Tentei fazer assim:

```
result = [x for x in range(0, len(list)) if list[x][0] != 0 and list[x][1] != 0]
```

Mas não me retorna a lista sem as posições que eu quero, só retorna os indíces.

Código abaixo até agora e que está dando erro:

```
list = [
    [1,2],
    [3,4],
    [5,6],
    [0,0],
    [7,8]    
]

for x in range(0, len(list)):
    if list[x][0] == 0 and list[x][1] == 0:
        del list[x]
```

Erro:

> IndexError: list index out of range

---

Agora eu fiz assim:

```
result = [list[x] for x in range(0, len(list)) if list[x][0] != 0 and list[x][1] != 0]
```

... E retornou a lista sem as posições que eu queria. É assim mesmo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro, não utilize `range(0, len(lista))` para percorrer uma lista em Python, basta fazer `item in lista` que é mais idiomático, legível e mais rápido. Segundo, não utilize o nome `list` para variável; como ela é o nome de uma estrutura nativa do Python, você estará sobrescrevendo o objeto e isso poderá gerar efeitos colaterais.

Se sua intenção é remover todos as sub-listas que possuem ambos os valores igual a zero, basta fazer:

```
filtrada = [item for item in lista if item != [0, 0]]
```

Desta forma, `filtrada` será:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Para ficar mais simples de entender, o código equivalente seria:

```
filtrada = []
for item in lista:
    if item != [0, 0]:
        filtrada.append(item)
```

Gera o mesmo resultado, mas demanda 4 linhas de código e é muito menos legível que a *list comprehension*.

Outra forma, que poderia deixar o código mais legível, é utilizar a função `filter`, que retorna a instância de um gerador que iterará sobre a lista original aplicando o filtro definido. Para este exemplo ficaria:

```
filtrada = filter(lambda it: it != [0, 0], lista)
```

Assim, podendo converter para uma lista com `list(filtrada)` ou apenas iterar sobre o gerador:

```
for item in filtrada:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Uma dúvida que veio, numa lista `[0, 1, 2, 3]` o `len()` dela seria 4, correto? no caso ao fazer um loop deveria usar `... range(0, leng(...) - 1)`? Já que o primeiro índice é 0 e o último é 3 e não 1 e 4

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Sim, o tamanho seria 4, mas o `range(a, b)` do Python define um intervalo `[a, b[`, isto é, vai de `a` até `b-1`. Por exemplo, `range(0, 4)` seria `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.